# Seeking vector file of extent of flood plain of 2010 Pakistan Floods?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, geohazard

I am looking to locate a shapefile or any vector file that can be used for analysis I am conducting of change in size of cropland in the Punjab region of Pakistan. The file of interest would reflect the area that the floods that took place in Pakistan 2010 and would provide me the ability to differentiate areas that were directly affected by the floods from ones that were not.

I have tried several outlets such as the Humanitarian Data Exchange and requesting it from several organization without any luck. I may have overlooked platforms where this data would be available that is why I am here for this help.